# How to use Java Expression Library (JEL)?

Tags: java, parsing, math

For a uni project we have to read in a user defined function in two variables from a text file. Example: `h(x,y)=sin(x^2+y^2)`.
It is important for our project that we can quickly evaluate this function multiple times with different x and y values.
So far we have been using mxParser which works good for this purpose but it is just too slow if we compare it to hardcoding the function into the program and using the java Math library.
So on my search I found the Java Expression Library(JEL) and I was wondering if it can be used for that purpose? How would it work to turn a string like `"sin(x^2+y^2)"` into something that we can evaluate with different x- and y-arguments?
Unfortunately the documentation on the official [website](https://www.gnu.org/software/jel/) isn't that clear to me.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Whatever you use is *always* going to be slower than hard-coding. You probably don't need to do more than cache the results of your parsing as executable code, rather than re-parsing every time. Parsing is *O(N)* and unlikely to be much different between implementations.

Answer (score 0):

Using mXparser please remember to create the objects before the loop statement, then in the loop just change the argument values. Then it should be fast enough :-)

The best way is to follow **mXparser's Tutorial**: https://mathparser.org/mxparser-tutorial/

- Section on **expression pre-compilation**: https://mathparser.org/mxparser-tutorial/expression-pre-compilation/
- Section on **efficient calculation in loops**: https://mathparser.org/mxparser-tutorial/efficient-calculations-in-loops/
- Section on **smart rounding settings**: https://mathparser.org/mxparser-tutorial/smart-rounding-settings/